# Assigning a static IP addresss for Ubuntu Server 22.04 running on VirtualBox

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, 22.04

I'm currently running Ubuntu Server on VirtualBox with a bridged connection, Ive attempted to create static IP address by editing the netplan yaml file, but I'm not able to ping google or my own loop-back address, and whenever I attempt to restart my network interface I get `Unit network.service not found`. Can someone please explain what I've done wrong? I'm still trying to figure out this technology.

Results of `ip a`:

[image: Image of ip a]

ipconfig from host:

[image: ipconfig]

yaml configuration:

[image: yaml configuration]

Comment: Please add the network settings of your host to the question. Please use "cut&paste" of the text instead of images, as they will disappear at one time and makes the question/answers useless for others. Reminder: It might be that others have the same problem and search for help in this forum.

Comment: Look at your Virtualbox output: "Host-only Network," which is not what you want. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly